# Question about Legendre's Theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

True or false:
$$
\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} \text { such that } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{n !}{2^{n+k}} \in \mathbb{N} .
$$

By intuition, I feel it should be false. Then I tried to prove it by contradiction that assumes it is TRUE for $n$ that :
$$
\frac{n !}{2^{n+k}} = a, a \in \mathbb{N}
$$

So it should be also TRUE for $n+1$ that:
$$
\frac{(n+1) !}{2^{n+k+1}} = b, b \in \mathbb{N}
$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{n !}{2^{n+k}}\cdot\frac{n+1}{2^{1}}=b$$
$$\Rightarrow a\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}=b$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a}{2}\cdot(n+1)=b$$

Then I realize that if $a$ is odd and $n$ is even, $b$ can never be a natural number and I can find the contradiction! And I am working on it right now. But I am wondering that am I on the right track?

Comment: Have a look at the [Legendre's Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml).

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226085/help-me-find-a-number-that-satisfies-this-divisibility-condition

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the largest $n$ such that $2^n | (2^m)!$

This $n$ is equal to $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m 2^{m - i} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{m - 1} 2^i = 2^m - 1$. This is because we can get one factor of 2 from all the multiples of $2^1$ ($2^{m - 1}$ of those), an additional factor of 2 from all the multiples of $2^2$ ($2^{m - 2}$ of those), an additional factor of 2 from all the multiples of $2^3$ ($2^{m - 3}$ of those), etc.

Therefore, we see that for all $m$, $2^{2^m}$ does not divide $(2^m)!$.

Then in particular, we see that $2^{2^m - m}$ does not divide $(2^m - 1)!$ for all $m$.

So for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, we see that $\frac{(2^{j + 1} - 1)!}{2^{2^{j + 1} - (j + 1)}} \notin \mathbb{N}$. That is, $\frac{(2^{j + 1} - 1)!}{2^{(2^{j + 1} - 1) - j}} \notin \mathbb{N}$.

Thus, your theorem is proved.

Edit: to be more precise, we see that if there were some $k$ such that for all $n$, $\frac{n!}{2^{k + n}} \in \mathbb{N}$, then clearly it must be the case that $k \leq 0$. For if $k > 0$, then $\frac{0!}{2^{0 + k}} = \frac{1}{2^k} \notin \mathbb{N}$. So write $k = -j$ for some $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the above remark proves that $-j$ doesn't work.

Comment: The question specifies $k \in \Bbb Z$, not $k \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: @RobertShore Correct, but WLOG it suffices to consider non-positive integers, which is the case I covered.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider what powers of 2 occur in $1,\ldots,2^N$ for some $N$. From the multiples of 2 we get $2^{N-1}$, from the multiple of 4 you get another $2^{N-2}$ (because we already counted a factor 2 for these we only need to count another factor 2), the same for higher power of 2.

So we get the 2 a total of
$$ 2^{N-1}+2^{N-2}+\ldots+2^{N-(N-1)}+2^{N-N} = 2^N-1$$ times.

Now, take $n=2^N-1$. Then $n!$ is missing another total of $N$ 2s, so $n!$ has a total of $2^{N}-1 - N$ 2s.

So can there be a $k$ so that $2^N-1-N \geq 2^N-1+k$ for all $N$? well, obviously not. So no matter how small $k$ gets, as soon as $N>-k$ this won’t work.

Test:
Take $k=-6$. We choose $N=7$, then $(2^7-1)!/2^{2^7-1-6} = 22664...75/2$.

Comment: Suppose $k \lt 0$.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes? Note that I said "no matter how small $k$ gets. The point is, that as soon as $N>-k$ (I notice I messed up the sign, because I tend to write $2^{n-k}$ instead of $2^{n+k}$, which makes less sense to me) $n=2^N-1$ will not satisfy this property.